# Mi sonido no se reproduce (HTML4)

Tags: javascript, html

Ahora estoy programando con **HTML4** porque en **HTML5** comienza a presentar errores. Una vez aclarado, comienzo:

Estoy haciendo una intro para mi página web, como tipo “video”.
Tengo un **setTimeout** en la parte del Javascript de mi página. En ese setTimeout quiero reproducir un **audio** para darle más estilo, pero por alguna razón mi audio **no se reproduce**. Ya he intentado de todo lo que se me ha ocurrido pero **no me ha funcionado**.
Toda mi intro funciona bien, a excepción del audio.

HTML:

```
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #000000; display: flex; align-content: center; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"><div><image src="code/images/intro.gif" style="width: 100%; display: flex; align-self: center;"></div>
<script>
setTimeout(function(audio) {
    var whoosh = new Audio("code/sounds/whoosh.wav");
    whoosh.play();
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(go) {
    window.location.href = "subpages/mainpage.html"
}, 4500);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

P.D.: Tengo todo el intro comprimido en un solo archivo para que no se me revuelva con las otras páginas.

Answer (score 1):

Por motivos de diseño, ninguna web puede reproducir audio sin que haya ninguna acción por parte del usuario. Los `play` solo van a funcionar si están dentro de un evento de usuario, como un onclick, ontouch...

Por ejemplo, en este código, la música solo se escuchará, hasta que pulses el botón, aunque ya haya saltado el `setTimeout`.

```js
var musica = new Audio("https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-ukulele.mp3");
musica.volume=0;

function activarSonido(){
  if (musica.volume==0){
    if (musica.paused){ // Si no está sonando, hace el play para "activar" el sonido, y lo para hasta que lo active el setTimeout
      musica.play();
      musica.pause();
      musica.currentTime = 0;
     }
    boton.innerHTML="Sonido ON";
    musica.volume = 1;
  }
  else {
    musica.volume = 0;
    boton.innerHTML="Sonido OFF";
  }
}

setTimeout(function(){
  musica.play();
  console.log("play");
},5000);
```

```html
<button id="boton" onclick="activarSonido()">Sonido OFF</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda. Al final decidí rendirme porque necesitaba que esto fuera 100% automático, probe window.onLoad y no funcionó. Voy a dejarlo sin sonido. Muchas gracias de todos modos.

Comment: He puesto un código de ejemplo.
No se puede hacer automático, porque puede ser muy molesto para el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de agregar este código en [w3schools (hoja de demo)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout) y funciona perfectamente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
setTimeout(function(audio) {
    var whoosh = new Audio("https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav");
    whoosh.play();
}, 1000);
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Como bien dice [@arnau-castellví](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/3440) es muy probable que no tengas ninguna lectura de acciones de usuario, pero eso lo puedes resolver fácil con la detección del movimiento del ratón o diferentes sistemas que existen de onload.

Pero si no es ese el motivo, revisa que tienes de host (si te dice que usas HTML4 debe de ser que tiene algo raro).